# Bootstrap4 different menu collapsible vs expanded

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Apologies if this has been asked before (I'm new to all of this and very much still learning, hard to find the answer on search).

I'm trying to have a collapsible navbar that when expanded, has the items separated by | (can be border right instead), but when collapsed and in a hamburger button the '|' separators do not appear.

At the moment they appear, code below, links to pictures:
Collapsed view (want to remove the '|':

[image]

expanded view (want to keep the '|' or at least, something that looks the same):

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark sticky-top">
                    <button class ="navbar-toggler" type ="button" data-toggle ="collapse" data-target ="#navvy">
                        <span class ="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse navbar" id ="navvy">
                        <ul class ="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item white"><a class="nav-link active navbar-brand " id ="Overview" href ="overviewpage">Overview</a>|
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item white"><a class="nav-link active navbar-brand " id ="CS50-nav"  href ="cs50page" style="border-bottom: solid 1px white">CS50</a>|
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active navbar-brand " id = "Portfolio" href ="Portfoliopage">Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a couple of rules with media query. For example in this snippet I added some borders right just in the desktop version.

You could even use bootstrap helper classes to display elements just in mobile or just in desktop view. Take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

I hope this could help!

```css
#navvy>ul.navbar-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Desktop versions*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  #navvy>ul.navbar-nav>li {
    width: initial;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  #navvy>ul.navbar-nav>li>a {
    border-right: 1px solid #666;
    padding-right: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
  #navvy>ul.navbar-nav>li:last-child>a {
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navvy">Menu</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar" id="navvy">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item white"><a class="nav-link active navbar-brand " id="Overview" href="overviewpage">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item white"><a class="nav-link active navbar-brand " id="CS50-nav" href="cs50page" style="border-bottom: solid 1px white">CS50</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active navbar-brand " id="Portfolio" href="Portfoliopage">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Are you suggesting I use bootstrap 3 instead of bootstrap 4?

Comment: Ah it works in bs4 as well!
I changed the border bottom to be underline with this so that they don't connect:

style= "text-decoration: underline;     
                            text-decoration-color: white; text-underline-position: under;"

The last part just makes a bit more of a gap between the underline and the text so is more what I'm looking for (frankly, looks better than my silly border underneath I had!)

Thank you so much :)